# Angular-material md-button automatic hover effect

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular-material as a main style framework for my website and I'm trying to remove the ***md-focused*** class added by default in the confirm dialog primary button.

After spend some time searching in the internet, i have found an issue that suggest the following answer:

```
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm({
    onComplete: function afterShowAnimation() {
             var $dialog = angular.element(document.querySelector('md-dialog')),
             $confirmButton = $dialog.find('md-dialog-actions').children()[1];

             angular.element($confirmButton).removeClass('md-focused');
         }
})
.title('my title'))
.textContent('myContent')
.ariaLabel('my aria label')
.ok('ok text')
.cancel('cancel text');
```

This solution works fine, but I don't want to use javascript to modify the DOM.

My question is if there's any way to delete the md-focused class using only CSS, overriding classes.

Any clue will be appreciated.

Thank you all!

**Update - Solved**

Instead of *onComplete*, I use **optionsOrPreset.focusOnOpen** and set it to false.

Here's the code:

```
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm({focusOnOpen: false})
    .title('my title'))
    .textContent('myContent')
    .ariaLabel('my aria label')
    .ok('ok text')
    .cancel('cancel text');

$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(...);
```

Comment: This saved my day.. :)

Comment: @MrASquare glad to hear (or read) that!! :)

Answer (score -2):

You just have to override every style you want with the keyword `!important`

```css
.md-button.md-focused {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

Comment: You should never use !important unless it's your last option, that's a bad practice...

Comment: Solved. Instead of "onComplete" and the function to edit the DOM, i used "focusOnOpen" and set value to *false*.
More info: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog